# File upload with jQuery and Spring MVC 3 - Request method POST is not supported

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am trying to implement the file upload with jQuery and Spring MVC 3. I get the error like "Request method POST is not supported", and I cannot understand why. I have the following files.

Spring XML configuration:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
     <property name="maxUploadSize">
        <value>1000000000</value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadScript() {
         var file = document.getElementById("file").value;
         alert(file)
         $.post("../backend/uploadScript", {
                file : file,
         }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("Inside the uploadScript " + data)
         }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Got error = " + errorThrown);                
         });
   }
</script>

<div>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addscriptForm" id="addscriptForm" action="">
        File to upload: 
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="uploadScript()"> 
</form>
```

Handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadScript", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap model){
    ModelAndView ret;
    String name = null;
    String message = null;
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        message = "File is empty failed to uploaded";
    }else if (file.getSize() > MaxSize){
        message = "File is too long to upload";
    }else{
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes(); 
            File dir = new File(File.separator + "tmp" + File.separator + "Scripts" + File.separator);
            if (!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            MultipartFile multipartFile = file;
            name = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            message = "File is uploded successfully";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ret = new ModelAndView("AjaxResponce", "responseMessage", "Failed to upload the file");
            return ret;
        }
    } 
     ret = new ModelAndView("AjaxResponce", "responseMessage", message);
     return ret;    
}
```

Please help me or give some suggestions to go ahead with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this link see what you are doing wrong http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-upload-file-ajax-jquery-formdata/